# My sample dylib is not working in iphone Device but working fine in Simulator

Tags: iphone, dylib

I have created a sample `dylib` with `add(int,int)` method. I kept this dylib in `usr/lib` and tried to call this method by including this in frameworks of my iphone application. Now this works fine with Simulator but not running in my Device.
Can any one give me clue Where I am going wrong?
Following are the *Error/warning* *messages* I got:

```
Error: ld: symbol(s) not found  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.  
Warning : libAddDll.dylib, file is not of required architecture
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dylibs are not supported on the iPhone you can only use static libs.

Comment: is this still the case? I want to use .dylib for my unity game to run on ios